# How can I modify os PATH in python 3 under Spyder or Jupyter Anaconda channels?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, environment-variables, spyder

I can't run an executable from python 3 within Spyder or Jupyter Anaconda Channels. This is because my system path is not recognised. If in my OSX Terminal I write:

```
activate myEnv
python3 -c 'import os; print(os.environ["PATH"])'
```

I get the content of my usual system PATH, but when I do it in python 3 through Anaconda channels Spyder or Jupyter-Notebook, under the same environment, i.e. myEnv, the PATH is different.

```
import os
print(os.environ["PATH"])
```

[image]

I understood this happens because python environments inherit from different processes, but how can I then set, under Anaconda channels Spyder or Jupyter, my usual environment, and PATH?

PS
I found other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346999/how-does-os-system-differ-from-command-line) similar to my one, but not sure to understand how to practically use the provided answers.

Comment: Do you want to completely replace PATH as defined in Spyder/Jupyter? Or just append additional paths to it?

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCordoba, just add my paths, cannot find where...

Comment: You need to add those paths to your `~/-profile` or `~/.bashrc` files and start Spyder or Jupyter in your terminal.

Comment: Hi @CarlosCordoba, I did it of course (actually they were already there, in fact, everything works fine out of Anaconda). Anaconda modified my .bash_profile file, thus I added them to it as well, but it doesn't affect the behaviour. This is exactly my point, I don't really know where else I should add those paths.

Comment: I added a picture of my Jupyter Lab, to better show the (to me unexpected) behaviour. Same happens in Spyder.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the picture, I understand what you meant now. I Spyder this should be solved since version 4.1.0, released 8 months ago. Jupyter doesn't have something similar by default (as far as I know).

Comment: Hi, thanks again. In the end, I added my paths to the conda.sh file directly, instead of to the .bash_profile modified by Conda during installation, and it works for both Spyder and Jupyter.